# Unable to login to the android stackoverflow app

Tags: google-account

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask.

I've the stackExchange Stackoverflow app on my android smartphone. I signed up to stackoverflow on my PC using my g+ account.

The app's login screen doesn't offer g+ login. I dont't have a user/pass combo set up. How can I log-in to SO on my android phone?

thanks!

Comment: The log in page has a "Log in using Google" button on my device. Is that not available for you? Does your phone have your Google account set up? I believe the SE app uses the system's account management APIs to sign you in.

Comment: While you asked the question at the right place, the most suitable place for the questions about this app (bugs/feature-request/ other issues) is [meta.se]. Use the tag [android-app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app) there.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see Log in using Google, which is strange, use "Login using another OpenID".